# Using Pandas to Read Excel with Column of Variable Type

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working on automating back-end Python data processing for an Excel data set provided to my system.  One of the columns should be formatted as text containing alphanumeric characters along with hyphen ('-') and period ('.') delimiters.

Excel is auto-formatting this column and converting two numeric values separated with a hyphen as a date.  So when I try to load with the Pandas library using read_excel(), it's using the Excel formatting and causing unwanted behavior.

For example: April 05, 2019 entered as "4-5" auto-converts to "5-Apr" but I want it to stay as "4-5".  Of course I could just open the file manually and change the column to text but that defeats the goal of full automation.

Using pandas.read_excel(), the column is dtype=object.  I tried to convert to str but it just keeps the excel format.  Then I tried to convert to int followed by str but the alpha characters throw an error.

Is it possible to make this work on the raw Excel file in Python or do I need to ask the owner of the data source to force the desired formatting?

Comment: AFAIK there's not a better way than to ask for the excel field to be stored as text, that way the '4-5' wont be cast to something else

Comment: I agree with @Yuca, this is the reason I try not to use excel as input, you never know what alterings excel will do to your file. This problem you have is a notorious one, also with thousand delimiter. 

Ask for a `.csv` file, which is much saver, especially for automation.